# How are my puzzles?

Tags: wordplay, cipher

Today, I told my friend about Puzzling SE and sent him the link to some of my puzzles.

His reply came, "Your puzzles are such a $50$ $96$ $5$".

"What do you mean to say?" I asked.

He sent me this:

> Mine is for. Kim = Tree. Rot it.

What did he mean about my puzzles? (I hope he had said something nice. *Fingers crossed*)

---

Note: You don't need to look at my previous puzzles to solve this one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hmm, this doesn't look good for you, but I'm probably a little off...
He may think your puzzles are a

> Nightmare

Explanation:

> His note reads "Minus four. Chemistry. Rot it"
>  I subtracted four from each of the numbers $50$ $96$ $5$ to get $46$ $92$ $1$.
>  I looked those numbers up on the periodic table to get the letters PdUH.
>  
>  Then I "rot"ed them backwards by four letters using the caesar shift to get "mare."
>  Then again, he may just think your puzzles are a lady horse?

Comment: Coz of [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/37632?m=29589823#29589823). And I am gonna kill him.

Comment: @manshu Ah, my answer makes more sense to me now :) Are those standard terms or local to PuzzlingSE?

Comment: Local PSE terms. However your answer is cool to me.